# Show Css Transition on hover

Tags: css

I am trying to make the bootstrap menu dropdown transition its opacity, Im very close but its just not working quite right I have looked a lots of examples and this is what i have come up with:http://jsfiddle.net/StudentRik/o642hw2e/

I would like the dropdown to appear when I hover over the `a` tag, it appears when you are at the bottom of the `a` tag due to the `position` How could I make this work?

Comment: Please include the minimal, relevant code *in the question itself* if you are looking to get debugging help. jsfiddles break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try.

```
li.dropdown > .dropdown-menu{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 17px;
   left: 0;
}

li.dropdown > .dropdown-menu{
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu{
   opacity: 1;
}
```